# Array max size in C language

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a small question that may seem a bit silly at first, but what is the maximum size that I can allocate to a dynamic array in C? Is it possible to increase this size?

I'm asking this question cause I had a segfault when I wanted to allocate a size of 10000000 random integers. I give you my code below, my code is correct !

```
typedef struct _Array   Array;

struct      _Array
{
    unsigned int        size;
    int         *data;
    int min, max;
};

Array   *random_array(unsigned int size)
{
    Array   *array;

    array = (Array *)malloc(sizeof(Array));
    array->size = size;
    array->data = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    if (array->data == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: memory allocation failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array->data[i] = rand();
    }
    return (array);
}
```

I got this in shell :

```bash
merge sort: 0.154297 second(s), 697539 random integers
merge sort: 0.164062 second(s), 777756 random integers
merge sort: 0.185547 second(s), 867197 random integers
merge sort: 0.214844 second(s), 966924 random integers
merge sort: 0.234375 second(s), 1078120 random integers
merge sort: 0.263672 second(s), 1202103 random integers
merge sort: 0.296875 second(s), 1340344 random integers
merge sort: 0.332031 second(s), 1494483 random integers
merge sort: 0.369141 second(s), 1666348 random integers
merge sort: 0.423828 second(s), 1857978 random integers
merge sort: 0.468750 second(s), 2071645 random integers
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `malloc` takes `size_t`, so theoretically it would be `SIZE_MAX`. If you use `calloc`, it takes both element size and number of elements, both `size_t`, so *theoretically* it might be able to allocate `SIZE_MAX*SIZE_MAX`, but in practice I doubt it can, but I am not aware of a universal rule about it. Probably depends on the implementation.

Comment: Can you post the code that got the segfault? That should not have happened unless you have a bug.

Comment: Sounds like [The XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) Why would you need to allocate max array size in the first place? Ideally what you would do is allocate a memory pool, then use that pool to your disposal.

Comment: The code he showed calls `exit` in that case.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. [Edit] and show the actual code you compile and run.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand I had a segfault normally I should have got the error message

Comment: Also show the verbatim out your program produces.

Comment: Don't cast the `void *` from `malloc()`.  Prefer passing the variable instead of the type to `sizeof`.  Add checks for NULL on all malloc/realloc.  You are missing the first one and if returns NULL your program will segfault.

Comment: I'm doing a project in C which aims to compare the sorting algorithm (execution time)

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` is s global thing so you usually do it once `main()`.

Comment: Identifiers that start with underscore are reserved.  It's undefined behavior if they happen to clash with something.

Comment: Where is your `main` function? Where are your includes?

Comment: On linux you can impose limits via the ulimit probably -m and -v are most interesting. cgroup have other limits. 40MB shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Post a [mcve], the *exact verbatim* code you compile and run.

Comment: @RyukShi, seg fault due to temporary space in merge sort in unposted code.

Comment: `Array` is a tiny struct. Don't malloc it but rather return it by value.

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce the segfault but there are changes I would make.  Mentioned most of them in the comments:

1. Don't use identifiers that are reserved (`_` prefix).
2. Don't cast `void *` from `malloc()`.
3. Check return value for all `malloc()`.
4. Prefer passing the variable instead of the type to `sizeof`.
5. Let caller decide how to handle error.
6. Move `srand()` to `main()`.  This makes it easy to reproduce errors if you print out the seed.
7. `free(array)` if `malloc()` of `array->data` fails otherwise it leaks now that we `return NULL` on failure.
8. `free()` array when done.  You probably want to write a function that has those two.
9. Prefer initialized variables (`Array *array = malloc(...);` instead of `Array *array;`).  `min` and `max` are not initialized.  Can you?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct Array {
    unsigned int size;
    int *data;
    int min;
    int max;
} Array;

Array *random_array(unsigned int size) {
    Array *array = malloc(sizeof *array);
    if(!array) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: memory allocation failed.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    array->size = size;
    array->data = malloc(sizeof *array->data * size);
    if (!array->data) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: memory allocation failed.\n");
        free(array);
        return NULL;
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array->data[i] = rand();
    return array;
}

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    Array *array = random_array(10000000);
    if(array) free(array->data);
    free(array);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I got the same segfault :/ I use WSL that's the problem ?

Comment: @RyukShi That sounds like something that should have been mentioned in the question. See e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/1707758/wsl-2-does-not-have-all-memory-available-to-it

Comment: I use WSL version 1

Comment: You should get an error now if malloc is failing.  If you are not then you didn't recompile your code.  Run the the above through a debugger and tell us where it segfaults.  It works for me.

Comment: @RyukShi cannot reproduce. Add some printfs and find out more.

Comment: The problem is going to be in the merge sort code which we haven't seen. The array setup appears to be ok.

Comment: Yeah, question is misleading (now that posted the merge sort output)... if my program segfaults let's figure out why, if not, then I suggest you accept his as answer or delete the question, and open a new question with a [mre] in particular with your merge sort code that does segfault.

Comment: I give you my repository github if you want more information "https://github.com/RyukShi/Sorting-Algorithms-in-C/"

Comment: I rarely follow external links.  It doesn't matter question was rightly closed, use feedback received and create a better question.

Comment: You are supposed to post your code here so you have one self contained question that doesn't rely on external links that might disappear over time.